# Subclassed RichTextBox OnTextChange event doesn't fire when text first set

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have subclassed a `RichTextBox` in order to add syntax highlighting, and it works fine when the text is changed manually. However the `OnTextChanged` event does not fire when the `Text` is first set in code.

The event code I have is

```
/// <summary>
/// When text changes keywords are searched for and highlighted
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (highlighting)
        return;

    int currentSelectionStart = this.SelectionStart;
    int currentSelectionLength = this.SelectionLength;

    base.OnTextChanged(e);

    String text = this.Text;
    this.Text = "";

    this.HighlightSyntax(text);

    this.SelectionStart = currentSelectionStart;
    this.SelectionLength = currentSelectionLength;
}
```

How can I get this event to fire when text is set from code e.g. `this.structureInFileTextBox.Text = obj.FileStructure;`? I've tried overriding the `Text` property but that makes Visual Studio crash and I have to edit it out of the `.cs` file before I can open the project again!

Comment: It probably crashes because if you override the `Text` property to say, call `OnTextChanged` if `Text` is set, you will find yourself in a forever loop. This is because you end up calling `this.Text = ""` in your `OnTextChanged` method.. see the problem?

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, so have assumed that isn't the correct approach to get what I want. I've tried using a `bool` to track when `HighlightSyntax` is running and hence return out of the `set` but no joy, VS still crashes on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this (I only changed `this.Text = "";` in `base.Text = "";`) :

```
/// <summary>
/// When text changes keywords are searched for and highlighted
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (highlighting)
        return;

    int currentSelectionStart = this.SelectionStart;
    int currentSelectionLength = this.SelectionLength;

    base.OnTextChanged(e);

    String text = this.Text;
    base.Text = "";

    this.HighlightSyntax(text);

    this.SelectionStart = currentSelectionStart;
    this.SelectionLength = currentSelectionLength;
}
```

and override Text property this way :

```
public new string Text
{
    get { return base.Text; }
    set
    {
        if (base.Text != value)
        {
             base.Text = value;
             OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```